# Combination :before and :first-letter is not working when adding display:flex

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

For some reason the `:first-letter` pseudo element in combination with the `:before` pseudo element is not working when you add `dislay: flex;`.

This should work, on [mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter) they say:

> A combination of the ::before pseudo-element and the content property may inject some text at the beginning of the element. In that case, ::first-letter will match the first letter of this generated content.

---

**See:**

`:first-letter` **Without flexbox:**

```css
.box:before {
 content: "Hello World";
 font-size: 30px;
}

.box::first-letter{
 font-size: 150%;
}

.box {
 width:280px;
 height:280px;
 border:1px solid #c39f76;
 box-sizing:border-box;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

---

**With flexbox:**

As seen the first letter is not increased in size even tho `:first-letter{ font-size: 150%; }` has been added.

```css
.box:before {
 content: "Hello World";
 font-size: 30px;
}

.box::first-letter{
 font-size: 150%;
}

.box {
 width:280px;
 height:280px;
 border:1px solid #c39f76;
 box-sizing:border-box;
  display:flex;
  justify-content:center;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 280px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

(Only tested this on chrome)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [the specification](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors-3/#first-letter):

> In CSS, the `::first-letter` pseudo-element applies to block-like containers such as **block, list-item, table-cell, table-caption, and inline-block** elements. *Note: A future version of this specification may allow this pseudo-element to apply to more display types.*

As you can read, a flexbox container is not listed actually. It will probably be in the future:

Answer (score 1):

The text element in the Flex container is not a text string, this is a flex element.

That is why `::first-letter` does not work