# Line clamp and capitalizing the first letter

Tags: html, css

I am trying to capitalize the first letter in a text and limiting it to max. 5 lines.

See this fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/1crvt37n/

```css
.capitalize-first-letter::first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.line-clamp {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="capitalize-first-letter line-clamp" style="width: 100px">
    this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
    this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
    this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
    this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
    this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
    this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In Firefox (Mac, Version: 110.0) it is working as expected, but in Chrome (110.0.5481.177) it is not working. The first letter is still lowercase. The line clamp works as expected in both.

How can I make it work in Chrome?

Comment: This looks like a bug with the webkit implementation of `display: -webkit-box`. You can use a JavaScript solution in the while it gets fixed

Comment: @ChristianVincenzoTraina this was also my thought, just wanted to verify this. I'll create a bug ticket.

Comment: I don't really know it's worth creating a bug ticket. Chrome seems to consider elements with `display: -webkit-box` to be flex containers (as opposed to block containers), in which case the `::first-letter` pseudo-element cannot be used. Given that most of the `-webkit-box` properties have been superseded by flexbox, Chrome's behavior is arguably correct.

Comment: See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57902033/combination-before-and-first-letter-is-not-working-when-adding-displayflex).

Answer (score -3):

Your other CSS is hidden your Text. So you don't see the right. Please remove  class or you modified right and don't hidden the text. With 1 row you need 1 div to help CSS can style it right.

The Row is greater than 5 you can use CSS to hide it via psudo class :nth-child(n+6)

```css
div.capitalize-first-letter::first-letter {
  text-transform: capitalize!important;
}

.hide_row_more_than_5 div:nth-child(n+6) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="hide_row_more_than_5">
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">
      this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
      <div class="capitalize-first-letter">this text should have a capital letter and only 5 rows...
      </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Supported on Chrome since version 1, Edge since version 12, etc. Just capitalization of the Dutch `IJ` is not supported.

Comment: Thanks for your noted, My mistake. I don't read carefully..

Comment: I think you failed to understand the question.

Comment: No, I understand clear the issue. His Code work right on Chrome, but he code wrong solution. and the Text is hidden. So that I give him a solution work right.

Comment: Your solution is not line-clamping a single div to 5 rows. It does something completely different.

Comment: no requirement about just use only 1 div. His requirement is "capitalize the first letter in a text and limiting it to max. 5 lines." And when read this we will have many way to process, why must is single div???

Comment: And you are not limiting it to 5 lines, you're limiting it to 5 elements. Size your container to `width: 100px` like in OP's example and see why your solution doesn't work. I reiterate my earlier comment: I think you failed to understand the question.

Comment: regards, But I still think you and me have different view :). So that's not a problem. But the one who know exactly is the owner topic. So I still keep my idea, and Hope you have a nice working day :)

Comment: @xuanhungNguyen The main reason for my requirement is that the text was originally entered by a user (html editor) and therefore I can only use one div. To make your solution work a lot of analyzing and restructuring would be needed. So that's why I have the mentioned requirements.